# Can I execute OpenCover on existing test result files?

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, mstest, tfsbuild, opencover

As part of the TFS Build we execute tests that generate trx files. I would like to execute on these set of files code coverage analysis using OpenCover, **without** re-executing the Unit Tests. 
Is there a way to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a little command-line & duck-tape but it gets the OpenCover and Test results in **1 pass**, and publishes test results and coverage to TFS or Visual Studio Team Services (previously VSO).

- Create .bat file `Run-Tests.bat` that calls `vstest.console.exe` to test your code with the `/logger:Trx option`

  - This creates a .trx file that [can be published to TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37676009/270155)
- Run the tests

  - `OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"Run-Tests.bat" -output:"OpenCover.xml"`
- Run [OpenCoverToCoberturaConverter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmLFT.png):

  - `OpenCoverToCoberturaConverter.exe -input:OpenCover.xml -output:Cobertura.xml`
- Publish the test results and coverage to TFS:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not - [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover) needs to instrument your code as it runs in order to determine which bits of code were executed.

Comment: Thank you. Do other code coverage frameworks have this ability?

Comment: What to determine code coverage based on the results of some tests? Not that I know of.