# Publishing test results through command line test runner in VSTS

Tags: automated-tests, azure-devops

I'm trying to use vstest.console.exe with the TfsPublisher logger in VSTS (cloud).

There's a URL example shown in the article for [TFS onsite](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/12/06/publishing-test-results-through-command-line-test-runner/), but I'm trying to work out what parameters to use for my VSTS build.  The example is:

```
/logger:TfsPublisher;Collection=http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection;TeamProject=MyProject;BuildName=DailyBuild_20121130.1
```

But I just get an error saying the build cannot be found in the project, e.g.

```
Error: Build "1234" cannot be found under team project "MyProject".
```

I believe the problem is the BuildName parameter.  My project and build definition have no spaces in the names.  I have tried various values, e.g.:

```
BuildName=%BUILD_BUILDID% (resolves to number, e.g. 1234)
BuildName=%BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME% (resolves to build definition name OK)
BuildName=%BUILD_BUILDURI% (resolves to url, e.g. vstfs:///Build/Build/1234)
```

The error message confirms that the environment variables seem to be resolving OK, but I can't determine what I should substitute for "DailyBuild_20121130.1" in my case.

Updated: My vstest.console.exe logger parameter currently looks like

```
/logger:TfsPublisher;Collection=%SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI%;TeamProject=%SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT%;BuildName=%BUILD_BUILDNUMBER%
```

Comment: What testing framework are you using? You shouldn't need to manually publish test results via CLI under most circumstances.

Comment: It's a cross-platform shared project - Android/Win32/Windows Store/iOS/WebForms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I effectively got the result I wanted using the Trx logger and one of the "Publish Test Results" build steps:

```
vstest.console.exe ... /logger:Trx
```

[image]

Comment: I've had to do the same thing. It seems like after the build has completed then "$(BUILD_BUILDNUMBER)" is enough, but during the built it isn't.. almost as if the build is staged. I've also found that no per test results are reported. I've resorted to producing a .trx then using the inbuilt "Publish Test Results" task too.

Answer (score 1):

The build name is generated by "Build number format" under build definition "General" tab. You can get it from ["BUILD_BUILDNUMBER"](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables#global-build-variables) variable.
[image]